# PHP Google Drive API V3: "Login Required" Error

Tags: php, google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-api-php-client

I'm using Google Drive API v3 in my app. I want to have a simple file upload using the API. But it's giving me an error saying "Login Required" even after logging in and redirected.

***gdrive_auth.php***

```
<?php

    require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

    $client = new Google_Client();
    // Get your credentials from the console
    $client->setClientId('MY CLIENT ID');
    $client->setClientSecret('MYS SECRET');
    $client->setRedirectUri('http://localhost/gdriveapi/index.php');
    $client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'));

    session_start();

    if (isset($_GET['code']) || (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token'])) {
        if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
            $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
            $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
        } else
            $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);

    } else {
        $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
        header('Location: ' . $authUrl);
        exit();
    }
```

***index.php*** (to which i'm redirected after authorization)

```
<?php

    require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

    $client = new Google_Client();
    // Get your credentials from the console
    $client->setClientId('MY CLIENT ID');
    $client->setClientSecret('MY SECRET');
    $client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'));

    $service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);

    //Insert a file
    $file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
    $file->setName(uniqid().'.jpg');
    $file->setDescription('A test document');
    $file->setMimeType('image/png');

    $data = file_get_contents('Capture.png');

    $createdFile = $service->files->create($file, array(
        'data' => $data,
        'mimeType' => 'image/png',
        'uploadType' => 'multipart'
        ));

    print_r($createdFile);
```

***The error message:***

> Fatal error: Uncaught Google_Service_Exception: { "error": { "errors":
>   [ { "domain": "global", "reason": "required", "message": "Login
>   Required", "locationType": "header", "location": "Authorization" }

Any solution for this?

Comment: You set the access token in the first script but not in the session. also... Not sure you need a client secret **and** and access token. I don't have time to re-read the docs right now but you should maybe ensure you don't get confused between the different OAuth flows and just use the one you actually need for this. Are you asking a user to authenticate themselves with a password, or are you trying to use a pre-defined service account? You seem to have got bits of code relating to both options

Comment: I've set the access token to session in first script. 
$_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();

Comment: sorry I mean "second" not "session". Typo. You don't set it in the **second** script. You'd need to get the value out of the Session and assign it to the new client object

Comment: @ADyson, can you kindly give example in the answer?

Comment: Just need to add `$client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);` to the index.php as far as I can see